# Windows SMB shares no longer accessible in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: networking, 19.04, fstab, cifs

Upon returning from a recent trip, my Ubuntu 19.04 autofs no longer mounts the cifs Windows 10 shares. When I click the Windows 10 machine in Nautilus under Other Locations, I get the error, `Unable to access location, Failed to retrieve share list from server, Network dropped connection on reset.` Does this have to do with SMB v1 and some Windows update? On my android phone, the file manager could also no longer connect to the Windows 10 machine, but after I installed an SMB v2 add-on, the phone can now connect to it. In my Ubuntu smb.conf file, I added `min protocol = SMB2`, but that did not fix it. Is there a way to get my autofs to mount the cifs shares again? I prefer to not go the fstab route, rather I want to keep using autofs if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to fix it. To smb.conf, I added `min protocol = SMB2`, `max protocol = SMB3`, `client min protocol = SMB2`, and `client max protocol = SMB3`. Then in terminal, did `service smbd restart && service winbind restart`.

Answer (score -1):

Solution that was helpfull to me was to activated SMB V1.0 Client and Server on windows. see attached file.
[image]

Comment: Please do NOT recommend SMBv1 due to related security issues.

Comment: +1 for the SMB v1 avoidance, and a thumbs up to the MS team for killing it. You'd be safer banging coconuts together and clopping your binary over a microphone. To be perfectly honest, you'd be better off running something like a Raspberry Pi on your network and let it deal with SFTP for file transfers. It's easy enough to find apps on all platforms to deal with the SFTP protocol